# Probability distribution of $\int_0^t \frac{W_s}{s} \,ds$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am currently working on an exercise that requires the knowledge of the distribution of $\int_0^t \frac{W_s}{s} \,ds$, where $W$ is a Brownian motion.

I can compute the distribution of $\int_{0}^T W_t \,dt$ easily by using the stochastic Fubini's theorem:

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^T W_t \,dt & = & \int_0^T \int_0^T \mathbf{1}_{[0,t]} (s) \,dW_s \,dt \\
& = & \int_0^T \int_0^T \mathbf{1}_{[0,t]} (s) \,dt  \,dW_s\\
& = &  \int_0^T T-s \,dW_s\\
& \sim & N \bigg( 0, \int_{0}^T (T-s)^2 \,ds \bigg).
\end{eqnarray}

However, such method seems to not work in this case, as I do not know how to express $\frac{W_t}{t}$ as a stochastic integral. Any suggestions?

Comment: $I$ in @Hans answer is a Gaussian random variable because $$I:=\int_0^t\frac{W_s}{s}ds=W_t\log(t)-\int_0^t\log (s)~dW_s=\int_0^t \log\Big(\frac{t}{s}\Big)~dW_s$$ is the limit of linear combinations of *independent* Gaussian random variables.

Comment: @ki3i: Your statement is correct. I just want to add that linear combination of Gaussian random variables is still Gaussian, whether the summands are independent of each other or not.

Comment: @Hans, Not sure about that claim; there are counter-examples like http://planetmath.org/sumsofnormalrandomvariablesneednotbenormal and  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#A_symmetric_example  (see the asymmetric example). Both have linear combinations of Gaussians that aren't Gaussian.

Comment: @ki3i: You are absolutely correct. My second sentence in my last comment was wrong.

Comment: @Hans, That's okay; glad to have been of some help.

Comment: @ki3i: I have mended my answer accordingly incorporating back a part of my first version and your argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the stochastic integral analogue of integration by part, which is a corollary of Ito's Lemma,
$$d(W_t\ln t) = \frac{W_t}{t}dt+(\ln t)dW_t,$$
so
$$I:=\int_0^t \frac{W_s}{s}ds=W_t\ln t-\int_0^t (\ln s)dW_s=\int_0^t \ln\frac{t}{s}dW_s$$
as $W_t\ln t\to 0$ in probability, as $t\to 0^+$. Since the random variable $I$ is a linear combination of independent Gaussian variables, it is Gaussian as well. Taking the expectation, it is zero.

The variance of $I$ can be computed at least two ways. One is using the expression above and compute
$$\mathbf E[I^2] = \int_0^t \Big(\ln\frac{t}{s}\Big)^2ds = t\int_0^1 (\ln x)^2dx = t\int_0^\infty y^2 e^{-y}dy=2t.$$
The last equality comes from differentiation (to the second order) under the integral. The second way is to compute directly from the original expression
$$\mathbf E[I^2] = \int_0^tdu\frac{1}{u}\int_0^tdv\frac{\mathbf E[W_uW_v]}{v}=\int_0^tdu\frac{1}{u}\int_0^t dv \frac{\min(u,v)}{v}=2\int_0^tdu\frac{1}{u}\int_0^u dv \frac{v}{v} = 2t.$$
So $I\sim N(0,2t).$

Comment: You seem to be using the fact that $W_t$ $\text{ln} \, t$ is independent of $\int_0^t \text{ln} \, s \,dW_s$ when calculating the variance. Knowing that $W_t - \int_0^t \frac{W_s}{s} \,ds = [1 - \text{ln}t] W_t + \int_0^t \text{ln} \, s \,dW_s$ is a Brownian motion, I computed its variance but couldn't get $t$.

Comment: @Richard: You are right about my previous version of the answer and I have corrected it to add the covariance. However, I have now changed the solution completely to take a direct and simpler approach.

Comment: But you haven't fully justified why $I$ is a normal random variable. The linear combination of any two normals is also a normal if they are independent. But in your previous calculations, $[1- \text{ln} \, t] W_t$ and $\int_0^t \text{ln} \, s \,dW_s$ are not independent, or else your previous calculations for the variance is correct.

Comment: You are right again. I have incorporated the integral by parts argument in my first version and @ki3i's comment into the current version of my answer to justify $I$ being normal.

Comment: I think this needs some explanation as to why the interchange of integrals is justified when computing $E[I^2]$.

Comment: @Richard: One can also see that $I$ is Gaussian by writing the Riemann integral as a limit of Riemann sums, and then writing those sums in terms of the independent increments of Brownian motion.  Using a similar argument, you can show that $\int_0^t W_t \mu(dt)$ is Gaussian for any finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0,t]$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I agree with your comment about Riemann sum of increments of Brownian motion and its Borel measure generalization. It is actually equivalent to the integration by parts approach in my answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Actually there is no interchange of integration in computing $E[I^2]$ as I have now made clear. There is, however, an interchange of expectation and integration. Is that what you are referring to? I think this is justified. Do you want me to either cite a theorem or prove it?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the interchange of the $du\,dv$ integral with expectation (which after all is another integral).  The obvious theorem to cite is Fubini's, but one needs to verify that the hypothesis of Fubini's theorem is satisfied, by showing that $\int_0^t \int_0^t \frac{E[|W_u W_v|]}{uv}\,du\,dv < \infty$ (note the absolute value inside the expectation).  That is what I meant by "justify the interchange of integrals".

Comment: @NateEldredge: I suspected that might be what you meant, but there are several integrals (including the expectation), so I did not know which you were referring to. Anyway, the inequality you refers to can be shown by Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. I shall do so later.